# How I can define this staircase function?

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I have a function $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ defined by

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac1{n+2},&x\in\left[-\frac1n,-\frac1{n+1}\right)\cup\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N$$

and I dont have a clue about how to define it in *mathematica*. I was searching in the language documentation and I found the function 'Piecewise' but I dont know if this can work with such a function as the above.

Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: isn't it just `f[x_] := 1/(Floor[Abs[1/x]] + 2)`

Comment: suppose `x=.21` for example, then `1/5<x<=1/4` so `n=4` and the result is `1/6` no?

Comment: @george2079 oh, I see... I will check it. Sorry, I didnt read correctly the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something resembling your mathematical notation you need to do this:

```
f[x_] := Module[{
   res = FindInstance[ ( 
       1/(n + 1) < x <= 1/(n) ||  -1/n <= x < -1/(n + 1)  ) && n > 0, 
     n , Integers]
   },
  If[res == {}, 0, 1/(n + 2) /. First@res]]
```

It is very slow, but Perhaps useful for more complicated cases.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use surely for future setups.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, n_Integer] := 
  If[(-1/n <= x < -1/(n + 1)) || (1/n < x <= 1/(n + 1)), 
   Evaluate[1/(n + 2)], 0];
```

Comment: Sorry but the function you are trying to represent is undefined, because $n$ is not defined, but in my function $n$ is defined as any natural number.

Comment: Ooopss... a simple slip, easily corrected in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun[x_] := 1/(Floor[1/Abs[x]] + 2)
fun[x_] := 0 /; Abs[x] > 1
Plot[fun[x], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> {1/# & /@ Range[-10, -1]~Join~Range[10], None}]
```

[image]